# Vue js and Data Table Panigation not Working

Tags: javascript, datatables, vue.js

Ok, so unfortunately I have come across this issue. So first a little about specs of my app.
I am using

1. **Vue.js**
2. **vue-resource.js**
3. **jQuery**
4. **jQuery DataTables**

Now because I'm grabbing the data through vue-resource, for some reason when the ajax call is final finished and vue imports the data to the table, **datatables** decides not to render pagination, and displays all 200 results on one page. Is there anyway to refresh **datatables** so it is rendered with pagination **after** it has been imported into the table? 
**My ajax call**:

```
       this.$http.get('getDispachedEmails', function(data){
          console.log(data['orders']);
          this.customers.push(data['orders']);
          var dt = $('#myTable').DataTable();
        });
```

**My Table:**

```
<table id="myTable" class="u-full-width">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Sex</th>
      <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-repeat="customers[0]">
      <td>@{{ firstName }}  @{{ lastName }}</td>
      <td>@{{ email }}</td>
      <td>@{{ trackingNumber }}</td>
      <td>@{{ address }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

<strike>**EDIT**
I have found out that none of the functions work. If i try to select any row, the table is instantly cleaned. My model (vue model) still has all the objects inside.</strike>

> SOLUTION:

I just set a wait time to initiate data tables after I collect the data via ajax request. It's a little ghetto, but a least it works. If I find a better fix Ill edit this post.

```
this.$http.get('getDispachedEmails', function(data){
  console.log(data['orders']);
  this.customers.push(data['orders']);
  setTimeout(function(){$('#myTable').DataTable();}, 5000);

});
```

Comment: Instead of `setTimeout`, have you tried [`nextTick`](http://vuejs.org/api/#Vue-nextTick)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A delay of 0 did the trick for me, although not sure why.

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#myTable').DataTable();}, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

I've built a dedicated vue grid component: [vue-tables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tables) . You might want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this table which works with vue 2 and vue 3 both
https://www.npmjs.com/package/data-table-vue